# Python: Quicksort in a recursive way

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement quicksort in python. It sorts the subarrays but when the recursion call return to the previous stage it mixes them up again. Can you please point me out where I am making a mistake?

```py
def quicksort(a):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return a
    else:
        low = 0
        high = len(a) - 1
        pivot = a[high]
        index = 0

        for item in range(low, high):
            if a[item] <= pivot:
                
                a[item], a[index] = a[index], a[item]
                index += 1
        
        a[index], a[high] = a[high], a[index]

    quicksort(a[:index])
    quicksort(a[index+1:])
    
    return a
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aren't *doing* anything with the returned values in the recursive calls `quicksort(a[:index])` and `quicksort(a[index+1:])` -- hence those calls have no effect. You also might want to replace `return a` by `return a[:]` since your code seems to be striving to return a new, sorted array rather than an in-place sort of the given array.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you John for your help. I have sorted it out.

Comment: @Maciej feel free to share a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

@ggorlen - solution to the above problem

```
def quicksort(a, low, high):
    if low < high:

        pivot = a[high]
        index = low

        for item in range(low, high):
            if a[item] <= pivot:
            
                a[item], a[index] = a[index], a[item]
                index += 1
    
        a[index], a[high] = a[high], a[index]

        quicksort(a, low, index-1)
        quicksort(a,index+1, high)

    return a
```